# Are there any non-scientific non-religious cosmology theories proposed in recent times?

Tags: metaphysics, cosmology

Are there any non-scientific non-religious cosmological theories proposed in recent times? I looked at various cosmological theories proposed and I only see scientific ones (ex: Machian universe), and also religious ones, but none of them seem to have come from philosophers. Is there any philosopher who proposed a new cosmological theory in recent times? I don't mind older theories as long as it was proposed after 1900.

Comment: See Whitehead's [Process and Reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_and_Reality).

Comment: Gurdjieff/Ouspensky cosmology? http://gurdjiefffourthway.org/pdf/cosmo.pdf

Comment: Also Bergson's [L'Évolution creatrice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Evolution_(book)) and maybe Teilhard de Chardin's [Le phénomène humain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phenomenon_of_Man).

Comment: I assume you mean "after" 1900.

Comment: Would "political" count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the Elephantidae Testudinata Theory of creation:

> About 15 billion years ago, after eternally climbing an infinitely deep stack of turtles, an elephant eventually reached the top.  The enormity of that accomplishment caused our universe to spring into being.

This is a non-scientific cosmology theory, because there is no physical means by which mankind can prove or disprove it.

This is a non-religious cosmology theory, because there was no supernatural revelation of it to mankind.

Except for a bit of plagiarism, it is entirely a product of my own imagination, and I make no claim that it is true or divinely inspired.

Other than similar instances of fantasy/fiction, I don't think there can be "*any non-scientific non-religious cosmology theories proposed in recent times*".

Comment: Does it count as a creation theory if it includes a preexisting stack of turtles?

Comment: If the question is how *our cosmological order* came into existence, then it sure can be. Indeed, all of the pagan cosmologies following Hesiod conceived of a pre-existing raw Chaos that was formed into order. Even though Chaos pre-existed our cosmos, it is still a theory of how our ordered cosmos came into existence.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis says "*it is still a theory of how our ordered cosmos came into existence*".  Yes, but it's clearly not scientifically provable, so either the ancient gods revealed it (making it religious), or some human invented it out of their imagination.  I don't see any fourth category.

Comment: @D.Halsey, the "*preexisting stack of turtles*" exists outside of our universe, so we have no way of scientifically testing their existence.  It's the creation of only our universe that we are considering.

Comment: The site rules ask for answers referring to theories in the published literature, not self-invented ones.

Comment: @Conifold, but that's my point. Excluding scientific and religious theories, the only possibility left is self-invented theories.

Comment: "Human mind" is broader than science, and speculative metaphysics is different from fantasy or science fiction. Philosophical cosmology has been pursued by some major thinkers, including Whitehead, Peirce and recently Meillassoux.